# R remove rows with value 0 in table column

Tags: r, function

I wrote a function for one of my regular tasks. I will just try to replicate my issue. Below is a random sample of how my data looks like. its an output of the function dput(mydataframe)

```
structure(list(respid = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), ssd = c(0, 
225, 236, 0, 221, 0, 0, 269, 265, 0), tea = c(228, 0, 269, 0, 
258, 241, 0, 222, 0, 256), juice = c(0, 236, 0, 236, 236, 0, 
236, 225, 242, 296), vad = c(236, 235, 0, 235, 235, 0, 235, 258, 
0, 236), energy = c(0, 235, 236, 235, 0, 236, 235, 0, 236, 0)), .Names = c("respid", 
"ssd", "tea", "juice", "vad", "energy"), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

now, my objective is to write a function to filter out the non-zero rows in 'ssd' column. Then it would look like this

[image: non-zero]

I wrote the below function in R

```
SoT <- function(df,key) {
  df2 <- df %>% dplyr::filter(key > 0)
  df3 <- janitor::adorn_totals(df2, where = "row")
  df4 <- tail(df3,1) %>% janitor::adorn_percentages(denominator = "row") %>% janitor::adorn_pct_formatting()
  return(df4)
}
```

my desired output is just the percentage of the summation of the column totals (after filtering for ssd > 0). In the above function, I am just giving the function 2 inputs. 1 is the dataframe and the other is the 'variable name' that I want to filter. I am calling the function like this:

```
SoT(df1, "ssd")
```

My desired result in the below pic is the one in green, but I am getting the one in yellow.

[image]

This means that the 'filter function' in the code doesn't work. But everything is working fine if I use it simply line by line instead of wrapping inside a function. Any suggestions ?

I haven't removed the images (just for your reference), but I have made the data and code reproducible as suggested.

Comment: Please learn how to make a *reproducible* question. This includes things like: (1) either name non-base packages or include code for non-standard functions (e.g., `adorn_totals`), or don't use them; (2) don't provide images of code or data, it cannot be copied or searched, breaks screen readers, and may not fit on all mobile devices (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272); (3) provide sample data in a more consumable format, such as the output from `dput(head(x))` (for desired, too) (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: `0` may not really be `0`. Could be 0.000001` and that result might occur. Can't really tell because you are only offering pictures, not data.

Comment: I understand, i ll revamp the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you program with `dplyr`, for instance specifying a `key` to filter with, you need to clarify from which environment you want `key` to be defined.

https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

In this case, to use the `key` you're passing in your function, you need two steps:

1) quote the `key` argument using `enquo()`

2) unquote it using `!!`

Together, these tell dplyr that you want to use the `key` that you've passed into the function, and not any other `key` that might be defined outside your function.

```
SoT <- function(df,key) {
  key_quoted <- enquo(key)
  df2 <- df %>% dplyr::filter(!!key_quoted > 0)
  df3 <- janitor::adorn_totals(df2, where = "row")
  df4 <- tail(df3,1) %>% janitor::adorn_percentages(denominator = "row") %>% janitor::adorn_pct_formatting()
  return(df4)
}

SoT(df1, ssd)
# respid   ssd   tea juice   vad energy
# Total 28.0% 17.3% 21.6% 16.8%  16.3%
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation. The code works fine now..! Really appreciate it.